# mask domain in url using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, web, url, redirect, dns

Heya thanks for any help in advance

So i have 2 domains both with same hosting company  namesco called `dmfoundation.org.uk` and `dmtrust.org.uk`.

`dmfoundation.org.uk`(no cpanel is apache http server) has all the files for my wordpress site and `dmtrust.org.uk` (cpanel) has no files inside it.

what i want to do is redirect `dmtrust.org.uk` to `dmfoundation.org.uk` but i want all the urls to appear as `dmtrust.org.uk/whatever` file name.
rather than displaying `dmfoundation.org.uk/whatever` filename.

any question feel free to ask.

Cheers,
Grant

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to point DNS from dmtrust to dmfoundation hosting.

Then in wp replace the site url to dmtrust (and eventually all links/src to dmfoundation in database).

Finally, in your .htaccess, at the root of you wp on dmfoundation, add a redirection to match every pages.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dmtrust.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hi there thank you for your suggestion i tried the method however i got the following issue 404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:
dmtrust.org.uk/web/ (port 80) @gael                                                                         
` #START SSL REWRITE - DO NOT EDIT
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#END SSL REWRITE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dmtrust.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler php52-script .php .php5 `

Comment: hi, @Grant.wilson as far as I can see, dmtrust.org.uk is still not pointing on the same server as dmfoundation. You need to redirect the domain in 1st place.

Comment: Heya @gael, I have just done it as maybe first time i did it incorrectly i will get back to you once it has resolved as it takes a while. thanks again

Comment: hiya @gael i believe they are both pointing to the same server however i am now getting an error saying that dm trust has redirected to many time  my current acces file looks like this                                                                                                             `  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dmtrust.org.uk/$1 [R=301]
#START SSL REWRITE - DO NOT EDIT
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#END SSL REWRITE 
AddHandler php52-script .php .php5   ` thanks grant

Comment: Hi @Grant.wilson I think you have a misconfiguration in your htaccess. You should open a new Question as It is not exactly the same issue now.